# How to connect with Github repository in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, github, repository, egit

I have created a repository in https://github.com. And installed `Eclipse Kepler` as the IDE. I want to commit my local file to this remote repository. By default Eclipse Kepler contains Egit for connecting with Git. So I just downloaded PDT for it and set it up for PHP programming. Now I want to know how can I connect my Eclipse with the Github repository.

How do I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated.